# Twenty Eleven header resize

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven

I seem to have a problem customizing the Twenty Eleven theme.
I would like that the top header above the header image to have a background color that goes from side to side in the window.
Found out that the problem may come from max-width set to 1000px, but could not find where to put it so it doesn't mess up the theme elsewhere.

How can I achieve to have a color on the top of the page (ex. like facebook top blue header) that has the width of the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Twenty Eleven [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) (don’t edit the main theme!) create a new `header.php` file, copy the content from the parent theme, and replace this part:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
```

… with something like this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div style="background:#345;color:#eee;padding:10px 20px;margin:0 -2em">Hello</div>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
```

But move the CSS into a copy of the `style.css`, and adjust the styles in the media queries too, because `body` doesn’t have a `padding` in smaller windows, and you have to remove the negative `margin` then.

Comment: Thank you, will try it later today and check back with the results.